# Hide the file name in the URL

Tags: html

what is the best method of hiding the file name in the URL from a developers side (who has no control over the server), for example if the site is www.123.co.za/contact.htm - i wan the user to only see www.123.co.za. an example of such can be seen here http://www.groupon.co.za

ways i know of is using one page and dynamically loading page content using ajax
the other is frames

(server options like mod_rewrite i cant use as i dnt have access to or control over the server)

Comment: Depends on the server used. For example, some servers are configured to automatically call `index.html` or whatever as default file when no file is been specified in the path. You could then just rename your file as such or put the needed logic in that file. So, if you elaborate more about the make/version of the target server used, you'll likely get more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

They are using index pages. That means they have a page such as index.html, index.php, or index.aspx, etc. All you have to do is create a directory (for example, 'contact') and put a file named 'index.html' within that directory. Then you can view www.123.co.za/contact/index.html as www.123.co.za/contact. Note that your allowable index page names may vary. If index.* doesn't work for you, contact the host and ask (sometimes it's default.*).

The catch to this method is that your page is now viewable by at lest three URLS (www.123.co.za/contact, www.123.co.za/contact/, www.123.co.za/contact/index.html). This can hurt your site in search engines for you may get penalized for "duplicate" content. You could solve this issue with mod_rewrite but seeing as you can't use that, you can't prevent the aforementioned scenario.